# Joomla Debug Console does not show Database Queries

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.4, mysql, database, debug

My Joomla 3.4.4 website is not showing `Database Queries` in `Joomla Debug Console` at the `site` front-end but it can be seen at the `Administrator` back-end.

**Below is the screenshot at the front-end**
[image]

**And here's at the back-end**
[image]

I believe it's not due to my custom template since I have already tried changing the template back to the default `protostar` template but it's still not working.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: does it maybe run out of memory? Can you check logs and try ini_set('memory_limit',;512M');

Comment: found no issue with logs and memory_limit @jdog

Comment: @jdog found the issue, please see my answer below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out that the joomla database driver is being overridden by another one which belongs to Falang component that allows you to manage all the content translations. Falang database driver has no debugging implementation and thus only disabling the Falang while debugging the site would solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is kinda of necroposting, but an issue still has no fix from Falang author, so here is it. In the file **./plugins/system/falangdriver/falangdriver.php**

Find *(309 row for Falang 2.6.0)*:

```
$db->debug($debug);
```

Change to:

```
$db->setDebug($debug);
```

Now Joomla debug information will contain all queries. The fix has been submitted to Falang author as well.